# Bootstrap Carousel with different hashtag URL ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have created a separate URL for each slide of the Bootstrap Carousel. However, it currently uses numbers with a hashtag in the following way:

```
domain.net/pride#1
domain.net/pride#2
domain.net/pride#3
```

Is there a way I can have it change to what I want? Something like:

```
domain.net/pride#events
domain.net/pride#press
domain.net/pride#schedule
```

Thank You.

```
<script>
    var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
    // Clear active item
        jQuery('.carousel-inner div').removeClass('active');

    // Activate item number #hash
    var index = url.split('#')[1];
        jQuery('.carousel-inner div:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    }

    jQuery('#PrideCr').bind('slid', function (e) {
        // Update location based on slide (index is 0-based)
        var item = jQuery('#PrideCr .carousel-inner .item.active');
            window.location.hash = "#"+parseInt(item.index()+1);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2) by the `data-name` attribute

http://glebkema.ru/tasks/so-38407398.html

```js
var url = document.location.toString();

if (url.match('#')) {
    // Clear active item
    $('#PrideCr .item.active').removeClass('active');

    // Activate item number #hash
    var index = url.split('#')[1];
    $('#PrideCr .item[data-name="' + index + '"]').addClass('active');
}

$('#PrideCr').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    // Update location based on slide
    var item = $(this).find('.item.active').data('name');
    if (item) window.location.hash = "#" + item; // Doesn't work on SO
    console.log(item);
})
```

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="PrideCr" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div data-name="events" class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150/c69/f9c/?text=events" alt="">
    </div>
    <div data-name="press" class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150/9c6/cf9/?text=press" alt="">
    </div>
    <div data-name="schedule" class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150/69c/9cf/?text=schedule" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#PrideCr" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#PrideCr" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

### 1) by the `id` attribute

I guess you can add the `id` attribute to carousel's items and use this attribute in your script. Something like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div id="events" class="item active">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
  </div>
  <div id="press" class="item">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
  </div>
  <div id="schedule" class="item">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
        // Clear active item
        jQuery('#PrideCr .item.active').removeClass('active');

        // Activate item number #hash
        var index = url.split('#')[1];
        jQuery('#' + index).addClass('active');
    }

    jQuery('#PrideCr').bind('slid', function (e) {
        // Update location based on slide
        var item = jQuery('#PrideCr .item.active').attr('id');
        if (item) window.location.hash = "#" + item;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this and it works but it jumps to the top of the page whenever I click next :( `<a class="right carousel-control" href="#PrideCr" data-slide="next">›</a>`. Any work around this this?

Comment: @ElaineByene Can you give me a link to your page?

Comment: Godly. Thank you so much :) :)